# Update DIV contents with current jQuery Cycle slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulties updating the contents of a DIV with the current slide of my jQuery Cycle slideshow.

Here is the slider function, it currently will output the current slide as an alert (and works).

```
$(function () {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'none',
    timeout: 1,
    continuation: 1,
    speed: 'fast',
    before: function (curr, next, opts) {
alert("Current slide " + opts.currSlide);
}
});
```

The DIV is as follows:

```
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

And the code I'm trying to use (to replace the end of the code above):

```
$(function (curr, next, opts) {
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.innerHTML = opts.currSlide;
});
```

Any thoughts on why the DIV does not update with the current slide #?
Unfortunately, nothing happens. I'm still learning my way around JS, so any pointers are much appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey - can you add what the cycle is? also, jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: Of course, sorry about that. I just put a copy of my local version on my server: http://buckmcgrane.com/360/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That variable in `opts` object (`opts.currSlide`) is not defined outside of the cycle function/plugin
so you would have to pass it to the function

```
$(function () {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'none',
        timeout: 1,
        continuation: 1,
        speed: 'fast',
        before: function (curr, next, opts) {
            getCurrSlide(opts.currSlide);
        }
    });
}):

function getCurrSlide(curr){
    $("#test").html(curr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/ZhaYK/) and there are a few thing to note. First your action added to the initial cycle will be removed when you hit your buttons. Here I have made the initial cycle do what you want and have added a button that you might use to get a 'snapshot' Note the selector to get only the currently visible image.

the meat:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'none',
    timeout: 1,
    continuation: 1,
    speed: 'fast',
    before: function (curr, next, opts) {

    $('#testNum').html("Current slide " + opts.currSlide);

    var $img = $("#slideshow img:visible").clone();
    $("#test").html('').append($img);        }
});

// The button will work after you click fast,slow, or reverse. 
//  The reason for that is the .cycle function above replaces it 
//  as fast as you can see it. 
$("#btnCopy").on("click",function(){
    var $img = $("#slideshow img:visible").clone();
    $("#test").html('').append($img);
});
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Thank you for taking time to also look into this. Thank you for setting up a fiddle too! The button is not working for me, however I really want to find a way to echo the current slide # and store it as a variable in PHP. This may be over my head, but it seems like a possibility. I tried to used the PHP DOM to grab the content of the DIV where the slide # was displaying, this didn't work as planned.

Comment: The button works after you click, fast,slow, or reverse. I updated the fiddle with some text. :)

Comment: Ah! This is awesome, thanks for your help Joe! I'm now going to attempt to store the src of the copied frame as a variable in PHP. Wish me luck!

Comment: A side benefit of this method (not passing the opts obj) is the ability to use any slider method that leaves only one image visible at a time. Glad this helps.